# Inverse statement to Rouché's theorem in complex analysis.

Tags: complex-analysis, rouches-theorem

Let $f$ and $g$ be two analytic functions with the same finite number of zeroes. Then there exists an analytic function $h:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ and a closed path $\gamma$ with interior containing all zeroes of $f$ and $g$ such that $|f(z)-h(z)g(z)|<|f(z)|$ on $\gamma$.

This really looks like some inverse statement to Rouché's theorem, but how can I prove it?

Comment: Are you assuming that the orders of the zeros are also the same?.

Comment: No, only the number of zeros. It turned up as a question in my exam last week and I am curious how to solve it.

Comment: Hmm. First consider $h(z) = f(z)/g(z).$ Note $h$ is nonzero and analytic on $\gamma$ since all poles are in the interior of $\gamma$, and that $|f(z) - h(z)g(z)| = |f(z) - f(z)| = 0$ on $\gamma$ and since $f(z)$ is nonzero on $\gamma$, we have $|f(z) - h(z)g(z)| < |f(z)|$. All that is left is to make sure $h$ has image in $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$... I think this should be doable by perturbing the definition of $h$ locally around the zeros of $f$ and $g$ with Blashke factors and some triangle inequalities, but I would have to tinker with it

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen: $h$ will be meromorphic, not holomorphic in general, and it will only be defined in the domain of $f$ and $g$, not in the whole plane. It is unclear to me what kind of perturbation you have in mind. Also note that somewhere you have to use the assumption that $f$ and $g$ have the same number of zeros

Comment: I'd also like to know an answer/hint for this problem...